# What sort of paper is "The Dark Pool" album cover made of?

Tags: paper, material-identification, canvas

I am trying to create something akin to this album cover to hang on my wall.

[image]

I'm not at all sure that the original was created this way, and maybe the cover is not even a photo of a physical object at all, but I think it could be done by printing out some images, tearing them and gluing together. The aspect I am most interested in is recreating the edges. What sort of material tears this way? I notice a lot of long fibers sticking out, is it canvas? Or some very thick paper?

Comment: The paper looks like it is not printer paper. It looks like thick pieces of paper. Also thinking older books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the images used for this collage look like torn from several coloured prints of astrophotographic images to me, printed on a heavy, presumably hand-made paper.
The image below seems to feature a rock texture (which makes sense, since the person is standing on it), and to have been cut with scissors.

You can see the Ben Day dots in some of the prints, but it is unclear if they were part of the original photo or due to the printing process. I assume the former, since they're not visible on all of the prints.

Based on the colours of the images and the fibres, I think they were torn from somewhat older books or even posters.

I guess it will be hard to print paper yourself and get this exact same look, but if you want to print the images yourself, I suggest visiting an art supply store and looking into the heavier deckle-edged sketching papers.

Alternatively you might want to go to thrift stores or second-hand book stores and find books with similar imagery.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ancient bookbinding printed paper or a kind of [paper marbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_marbling). There's a large classification list and examples at the University of Washington [Digital Collections](https://content.lib.washington.edu/dpweb/patterns.html)

[image]
<sub>*Image from [carnegielibrary.org](https://www.carnegielibrary.org/discover-historic-bookbinding-marbled-endsheets/)*</sub>

More printed bookbinding paper classification at [The Binder's Art](https://pius.slu.edu/special-collections-exhibits/exhibits/show/binder-s-art/decorative-papers/paste-paper/pulled-paste).

[image]